# Is there a way to use a custom TestNG reporter with Junit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, testng

I have a custom TestNG reporter something like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

public class CustomReporter implements IReporter{
    @Override
    public void generateReport(List xmlSuites, List suites,
        String outputDirectory) {
        //Iterating over each suite included in the test
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            //Following code gets the suite name
            String suiteName = suite.getName();
        //Getting the results for the said suite
        Map suiteResults = suite.getResults();
        for (ISuiteResult sr : suiteResults.values()) {
            ITestContext tc = sr.getTestContext();
            System.out.println("Passed tests for suite '" + suiteName +
                 "' is:" + tc.getPassedTests().getAllResults().size());
            System.out.println("Failed tests for suite '" + suiteName +
                 "' is:" + 
                 tc.getFailedTests().getAllResults().size());
            System.out.println("Skipped tests for suite '" + suiteName +
                 "' is:" + 
                 tc.getSkippedTests().getAllResults().size());
          }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to use it for my JUnit tests. Is there any easy way different than this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Include the code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: where is your reporter code? what have you implemented IReporter or Listener?

Comment: I am unable to add reporter code here, but I have implemented  IReporter

Comment: I have added the custom reporter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue with running Junit tests under TestNG using this method: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_run_junit_tests.htm